# Pass multiple values for each selected option in selectInput R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to combine values into one `selectInput` for that to be passed on to another function. So here is my code where the user selects the first input and the values should be `survey = 1` and `youth = FALSE`.

```
library(shiny)

output$choose_wave <- renderUI({
  selectInput("selected_wave", "Wave", choices = list(
    "Wave 1- Adult" = wave = 1, youth = FALSE,
    "Wave 1- Youth" = wave = 1, youth = TRUE,
    "Wave 2- Adult" = wave = 2, youth = FALSE,
    "Wave 2- Youth" = wave = 2, youth = TRUE
  ))
})
```

What is the better way to pass two values with one input?

Comment: You could use `switch` in your  code so that the selected option is treated accordingly but I don't see a way to do that with the input alone.

Comment: Can a select input shiny click let you select a list itself? Sounds strange. Not sure if it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

Either `selectizeInput` or `pickerInput` (part of the `shinyWidgets` package) will do what I think you're asking for. This is an example using `pickerInput`, where you can divide the two kinds of factors into groups and allow multiple selections that end up getting grouped into the output. Here is a minimal example.

```
devtools::install_github("dreamRs/shinyWidgets")
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("choose_wave"),
  h5("Value from selected wave:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("select_values")
)

server <- function(input,output) {
  output$choose_wave <- renderUI({
  pickerInput("selected_wave", "Select one from each group below:", 
          choices = list(Wave = c("Wave 1" = 1, "Wave 2" = 2), Youth = c("Adult"=FALSE, "Youth"=TRUE)),
                         multiple = T, options = list('max-options-group' = 1))
  })
  output$select_values <- renderText({as.character(input$selected_wave)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**UPDATE:**
The development version of `shinyWidgets` now allows limits on the number of selections per group (Thanks Victor!). Code above has been updated to limit selections to one per group, but you'll need to use the development version for it to work.

**The menu layout:**

[image]

**The values:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an if/else? May be more bulky but it works. Also does that input work, I usually assign a value to a text input.

```
if(input$wave==1 #or whatever the input is actually equal too){
wave = 1
youth = FALSE
}else if(input$wave==2){
wave = 1
youth = TRUE
} and so on..
```

I would say assign inputs to a value first and then assign extra data you need.